# Creating RASA Chatbot with some specific conditions

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, rasa, rasa-core

I want to create a chatbot where,

I have a branch of questions and answers like,

```
Q1. How are you
A1. - Fine.
    - Good.
Q2. Do you like travelling?
A2  - Yes
    - Absolutely
    - I like it.
Q3. Did you ever use RASA chatbot?
A3  - Yes
    - Almost 2 years.
```

now,

1. If I ask questions to the chatbot but miss some questions like forget to ask Q2, the chatbot will say that end of the conversion that I miss that questions,
2. After the chatbot say I miss some questions have to go throw all the questions from start again but,
3. When I ask those questions again the chatbot will give different answers than it gives 1st time.

   Example: 1st time when I ask Q1 and Q3 it gives answers **-Fine** and **-Yes** but when 2nd time I go throw the process for Q1 and Q3 it has to give different answers than **-Fine** and **-Yes**.

Now my questions are,

1. Is it possible to make a chatbot with RASA where it will follow the three conditions up there?
2. If not then is any sort of alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, all three conditions are possible.
Please correct me as I understood your question,
I am adding follow solution as per the below understanding:
You want your assistant to ask `How are you?` and end-user answers `Fine/Good`,
and so as Q2 and Q3 do.

**Solution**
For this to work, you have to use forms in Rasa. Below is a simple example for using this functionality.

1. Make sure you have form for these questions and slots added.(facing issue, following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/u6xOgR3jEMU))
2. Go to your actions.py
3. Add validations for each slot you have. Here, you will find just one example here as an example.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List

from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker, FormValidationAction
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher

from utils.utils import get_html_data, send_email


class ValidateContactUsForm(FormValidationAction):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "validate_contact_us_form"

    def validate_name(
        self,
        value: Text,
        dispatcher: "CollectingDispatcher",
        tracker: "Tracker",
        domain: "DomainDict",
    ) -> Dict[str, str]:
        if value in ["Fine", "Good"]:
            return {"name": value}
        else:
            # return {"name": None, "requested_slot": "name"}
            return {"requested_slot": "name"} # to request the same slot again, 
            # assistant will ask same question again.
```

**Note**: `return {"name": None, "requested_slot": "name"}` This will close the form and restart the whole form, in this case, the form has just one slot, if you have more slots you have to nullify them too.